# csrf validation failed when I login

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, csrf

I have a view in my django backend called `getUserInfo` that will return the user's info as json format.

This is my view:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def getUserInfo(request):
    if request.user.username:
        serial = userInfoSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serial.data)
    else:
        return Response({"notLoggedIn": True})
```

When I'm not logged in ajax request are working ok but when I login to a user account I get an "forbidden" error and it says csrf validation failed. I am also refreshing the csrf token every time the user logs in or out.

So it should work but it is not working.

This is my ajax request:

```
function login(){
    getcsrf();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/login/',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "XCSRF_TOKEN": csrf
      },
      data: {
        username: $("#l-username").val(),
        password: $("#l-password").val(),
      },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if(data.msg){
        console.log(data.msg)
        $(`<div class="p-2 bg-danger">`+data.msg+`</div>`).prependTo('#message-box')
      }else{
        getcsrf();
        getUserInfo();
      }
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
}
```

The function `getcsrf` refreshes the global variable containing the csrf-token value called "csrf" and then I send my ajax request. After the request I refresh it again. I'm sure the value of csrf token changes every time I am refreshing it when user logs in or out but server always says "forbidden".

I have inserted this code in my settings.py file:

```
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "HTTP_XCSRF_TOKEN"
```

and I am sending ajax request with a header called XCSRF_TOKEN

Can any one help me?

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay let me answer it my self.
i cleared my browser cookies and then it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
headers: {
        "HTTP_XCSRF_TOKEN": csrf
      },
```

so that it matches the header name in your settings file.

Comment: it's no need to do that, django will convert all the words to upper case and replaces all hyphens with underscore then it'll add HTTP_ prefix to it so my header will be HTTP_XCSRF_TOKEN that corresponds to my csrf header name in my settings file also i said my ajax request works but when i login to my account it doesn't work

Comment: in other words POST requests for not-logged-in users is not forbidden but it is forbidden for logged-in users